# PHP simple xmlRpc for web application

Tags: php, xml-rpc

how to write simple xmlRpc server for create and manage web application from client, i want to write server response to software such az office word and etc.

wordpress xmlRpc can get topic and other method for quickly using web site and manage from client. can you help me and introduction how to write that? i want to can use client softwares

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs to get you started : http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php

There is a tutorial on getting started with xmlrpc in wordpress: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/xml-rpc-in-wordpress/

Also Zend Framework Offers a good XmlRpc Server Component http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.xmlrpc.server.html

Google is your friend here... and if you want to emulate the capabilities of Wordpress remember wordpress is opensource which means you can pop the hood and see what makes it tick.

Comment: thanks. second link is client side, i want to write server side like with wordpress and using client software.

Comment: thanks. can i use wordpress classes and change that for my own website? editing wp-load.php and server class

Comment: you would have to review the licensing but I believe so.